# Calling dynamic value in Footer in BIP RTF

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, siebel

I have a requirement, where i have to print account number in the footer, the account number is different in each page. I did <?for-each@section: , but its not working as its fetching all the account number and dispaying in the footer, any help?

Comment: @EdHayes3  - Need ur help here

Comment: You have to group by account number. And the <end-of> that group should be after your footer.

Comment: Can you share the template and XML? Alternatively, please elaborate more in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies @EdHayes3 , but i am new and i dont know how to attach RTF here, kindly guide me

Comment: You can paste screenshots to your question if it's small enough. Making your example small and pasting images here is best. Else, use https://wetransfer.com/

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your prompt support and replies, the issue got fix :) , but i must say, u guys motivated me a lot !